# Is there any faster alternative for matrix exponential?

Tags: matrix, numerical-integration

Lets define matrix $M$ as

```
M = {{ Cos[
 t ]^2, - (2 Cos[t ] + 
    I  Sin[t ]) ((E^(-I t ) - E^(I 2 t )) (s + 2))}, { -8 I  Sin[
  2 t ], (2  Cos[t ] - 
   I  Sin[t ]) ((E^(I t ) - E^(-I 2 t )) (-s + 2))}};
```

I'd like to find the matrix exponential of $B$, which can be done by `MatrixExp`. It works for the above matrix, and the result is long and ugly. But the matrix of my problem is much more complicated. It is a 6 by 6 matrix, and each element includes the summations and subtractions of trigonometric and exponential terms, similar to (but more complicated than) the above matrix. Even worse, after finding the matrix exponential, I need to take an integral over each element, say, from $t_1$ to $t_2$, where $t_2>t_1$. If I use `MatrixExp` it takes a very long time, and if I want to do the integration it becomes much longer. Especially, if I write `Integrate[MatrixExp[M],{t,t1,t2}]`, I'm not sure whether it yields the results.

Do you know a faster alternative method that is suitable for more complicated functions?

Revise:

To clarify my problem well, I have a system of linear differential equations with "variable" coefficients:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}c=M(t) c+\lambda(t)+n(t)$$
In other words, the elements of $M$ are time dependent.

I already know how to find the solution if the coefficients are constants, but for the variable case the only method I know is this:
[image]

Here $\mathcal{T}$ is called time-ordering operator and guarantees that earlier time acts first. As you see, this requires both integration and matrix exponential. Also, one should note that in the second term $\tau$ is the integration variable. So, if we can assign a number to $t$, we cannot do that for $\tau$.

Comment: Unfortunately `MatrixExp` is already quite optimized. There are some implementations lying around the site, but ultimately you’re just doing different approximations of a matrix exponential that `MatrixExp` would do already. However, I will say two things: 1. Use numerical values, this speeds up evaluation by an incredible amount. And 2. Consider if you can apply a Magnus Expansion, and go that route. Much fewer instances of using `MatrixExp` and larger time steps.

Comment: Do you actually need the matrix exponential, or do you just need the integration? If the latter, you can hold off on calculating the matrix exponential until you've assigned numbers within `Integrate[ ]` and calculate then. Many orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Sometimes the heuristics for method selection used by `MatrixExp` do not give the "best" possibility. You could try doing it by hand using e.g. a Jordan decomposition, to see if that gives a better result. Also, would integrating first help? Or termwise integration of the Taylor expansion for the matrix exponential?

Comment: Saeid, are you trying to use `MatrixExp` as an integrator?

Comment: @CATrevillian I have revised my question. See what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have revised the problem.

Comment: @MikeY I need both. See the revised question.

Comment: Saeid, look up the Magnus Expansion, it avoids use of the Dyson operator and lets you use bigger time steps thereby reducing the number of integrations and Exponentials you must perform. I will seek to provide you an answer with the method this evening!

Comment: You could use a regular [Runge–Kutta integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge–Kutta_methods) to solve the differential equation without going into matrix exponentiation.

Comment: @Roman I have seen numerical works with Runge-Kutta method, but as you see in the above integral, $\tau$ is an integral variable, not a number. Do you know how to deal with that? In other words, I have to break an interval from $\tau$ to, say, 5. How it is possible?

Answer (score 5):

Just solve the differential equation without worrying about matrix exponentiation:

```
NDSolve[{c'[t] == M[t].c[t] + λ[t] + n[t], c[0] == {1, 0}}, c, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Is it possible to uncover the methods used within a solution done in this manner? Can you clarify this point?

Comment: @CATrevillian there's a lot of info on methods on the [`NDSolve docu page`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html). You can even define your own integration method and [use it as a plugin](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html).

Comment: I thought I understood NDSolve, and now I know I know enough to not know enough! Thanks for the link to the plugin system. I’m overall curious how this compares to a Magnus Expansion, so I’ll have to do some investigating.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, since not sure exactly what you need, but laying it out here...

Assuming your `s` eventually takes a value, let `s=1`. Then you can get the numerical integration for the terms of your matrix rapidly by holding off on the matrix exponential until you've set numbers. Define your matrix `B` as a function:

```
bb[t_?NumericQ] := {{Cos[t]^2, 
                    -(2 Cos[t] + I Sin[t]) ((E^(-I t) - E^(I 2 t)) (s + 2))}, 
                    {-8 I Sin[2 t], 
                     (2 Cos[t] - I Sin[t]) ((E^(I t) - E^(-I 2 t)) (-s + 2))}}
```

Then `NIntegrate`. I am using `Hold` to delay picking off the element of the matrix until you have a matrix, otherwise you get a message that you can ignore anyway.

```
s = 1;
NIntegrate[Hold@(MatrixExp@bb[t])[[2, 1]], {t, 0, 2}]//Timing
(* 0., 864.408 + 1079.91 I *)
```

This is actually faster than getting the matrix exponential first in symbolic form, and then integrating.

```
meb = MatrixExp[B];
s = 1;
NIntegrate[meb[[2, 1]], {t, 0, 1}] // Timing
(* {0.03125, -780.294 + 999.49 I}  *)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this is actually doing? Awesome!